# In Relative Layout as alignParentBottom is used,How the same can be used in Constraint layout in my code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In the given image I used android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for second text view to acquire the remaining available area towards bottom.

How this(second text view to acquire available space towards bottom) can be done in Constraint layout.

Converting relative to constraint layout not producing same results here.

Relative layout

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#499989"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
        android:background="#499989"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` and `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` is to make the views like `match_parent`.

`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"` so the view will be below the tv1.

And `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` is that the view will strech till the bottom of the parent (screen)

Comment: Thanks for helping...but this is just shifting the second text view to bottom.

Comment: but this is not working..its just shifting the second text view to bottom.I want my second text view to acquire the complete available space vertically.

Comment: There is a constraint layout....then a text view..just below first text view there is second text view(having background color green and text color black) ....Now I want my second text view to fill the available space starting from the bottom edge of first text view to the bottom of screen(showing background color green). supportingImage provided with question.